# Edit Multiple States At Once in Flash Builder 4

Tags: apache-flex, flash, flex4, gumbo

While in Design mode in Flash Builder 4 (gumbo, beta 2), is it possible to edit multiple states at once? In the "states" window, it would seem like I should be able to shift-select multiple states so changes made will affect all the selected states, and if all are selected it will not add the state selector to the property in the mxml tag. No?

Comment: would be a really useful feature if they had that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way in flex/flash builder to make a change to multiple states at once.  What you can try to do though, and im not sure this will do what you are wanting in this particular case, but you can make your states based on one particular state.  Then when you change the base state it will apply to the states that are based on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply copy the code that was generated from the changes in one state to a new state.